# React Flux always showing main domain instead transistion url in heroku DNS?

Tags: reactjs

**In *.herokuapp.com**

http://**.herokuapp.com/accounts

**In Custom Domain**

http://**.com/

I am using react 0.13 router, used Router.HistoryLocation and working fine with slash based urls in herokuapp domain, when it links to actual domain, It moving into accounts. but in browser url showing only main domain.

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed by configured CNAME record in DNS Provider settings.